# How to update an object of objects using its id in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, javascript-objects

I have this object of objects and i want to update this object of objects using the id that each object have this is my code:

```
 lists = {
    id3: { id: 'id3', name: 'Capitan America', job: 'superHero' },
    id4: { id: 'id4', name: 'Spider-man', job: 'Pro footballer' } 
 }

 function updateItem(id, property,value) {
    return (lists[id] = { ...lists[id], [property]: value });
 }
```

if i put it like this it works but i want to do it with just two parameters.  Like this:

```
function updateItem(id, property) {
   return (lists[id] = { ...lists[id], property);
}
```

Comment: `lists[id][property] = value`

Comment: i need to use just two parameters

Comment: If you want to update a nested object, you cannot use just two properties.  You need the id to identify which nested object to update, and the key and value to know what to set, and what to set it to. (provided you don't hard code any of those three)

Comment: You can only do the second with 2 parameters if you know the name of the property you want to add/change, then name the parameter accordingly

Comment: thank you can you give me an example

Comment: Well you already have the example....your second one produces `{ id: 'id3',... , property: someValue}`. Same name as the parameter

Comment: The other possibility is if you pass `property` as an object (like `{ name: 'NewName' }`), and then you could use `lists[id] = { ...lists[id], ...property }`

Comment: Personal opinion, and I readily admit it; creating an entirely new object just to update a single property on the object is..... weird.

Comment: @Taplar I think the idea here is the OP being able to just pass two params to update x number of properties for a given object with `id`... If you read his opening statement carefully he's stating that " i want to update this object of objects using the id" so really he didn't limit himself in terms of the number of properties to be updated. By creating a new object that can then be passed as a param is viable because then he can specify as many properties in there that he wish to update as possible. I think that's the whole idea.

Comment: @MosiaThabo I'm not saying it will not work.  I'm just saying I'd probably use Object.keys or Object.entries, loop over that, and update the original rather than creating an entirely new one.

Comment: Fair enough, but then for those can work for his initial scenario, you'll have to match an `id` and the name of the property. I agree that's another option! Can you perhaps create a repro of this using  loops as an answer below but strictly using only two params?

Comment: I'll upvote you for that! :)

Answer (score 0):

**OPTION 1**

You can instead pass the `id` of the object, and pass a simple object representing a property with it's corresponding value like `propertyObj= { propertyName: propertyValue}`. And then spread that object within the main object defined by that `id`:

```js
let lists = {
    id3: { id: 'id3', name: 'Capitan America', job: 'superHero' },
    id4: { id: 'id4', name: 'Spider-man', job: 'Pro footballer' }
 }

// You can pass an id, and a simple object updating the targeted property
function updateItem(id, propertyObj) {
  lists[id] = { ...lists[id], ...propertyObj};
}

// test for the updateItem
updateItem("id3", {"name": "Steve Jobs"});

//Let's print and see if it was updated.
console.log(lists);
```

---

**OPTION 2**

Another option would be to associate the `updateItem()` function with the object itself and set it as a method, since we're dealing with properties, why not?

```js
let list = {
  id3: { id: 'id3', name: 'Capitan America', job: 'superHero' },
  id4: { id: 'id4', name: 'Spider-man', job: 'Pro footballer' },
  // let's defined update method that receive same params
  update: function(id, propertiesObject){
    this[id] = {...this[id], ...propertiesObject};
  }
}

// Let's update the list using it's built-in update() method
list.update("id3", {"name": "Jeff Bezos"});

// Let's print the Updated list
console.log(list);

// NOTE: your object can have many properties in it that you wish to update in your original list.
```

Comment: OP already stated this version worked. How does this answer the actual question?

Comment: My first version works with 3 parameters but i want to use just 2

Comment: @EdivaldoGonçalves Yes sorry I missed that. When you mean two parameters I'm assuming that it doesn't matter if any of those parameters are a object or not right? Then if that's the case, check my updated answer where you can pass an `id` and an `object` representing the property.

Comment: Cool man, my problem is that I just jumped in and I didn't read the question properly. Sorry about that.

Answer (score 0):

If you are sure to call the update function with an object

```js
lists = {
    id3: { id: 'id3', name: 'Capitan America', job: 'superHero' },
    id4: { id: 'id4', name: 'Spider-man', job: 'Pro footballer' } 
 }

 function updateItem({id, netWorth}) {
    return (lists[id] = { ...lists[id], netWorth });
 }
 
 console.log(updateItem({id:'id3', netWorth: '$200M'} ))
```

Two ways you can do this: